# Adding a new element to an array in a hash of arrays

Tags: perl, data-structures, hashtable, associative-array, perl-data-structures

I want to read and save the content of a file in a hash of array. The first column of each row would be the key.
Then, I want to read the files in a directory and add the file name to the end of the array according to the key!

file ($file_info)

```
AANB    John    male
S00V    Sara    female
SBBA    Anna    female
```

files in the directory:

```
AANB.txt
SBBA.txt
S00V.txt
```

expected output:

```
AANB    John    male    AANB.txt
S00V    Sara    female  S00V.txt
SBBA    Anna    female  SBBA.txt
```

Here's the script itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %all_samples=();
my $file_info = $ARGV[0];

open(FH, "<$file_info");

while(<FH>) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split("\t| ", $_);

    push(@{$all_samples{$line[0]}}, $_);
}

my $dir = ".";
opendir(DIR, $dir);
my @files = grep(/\.txt$/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    foreach my $k (keys %all_samples){
        foreach my $element (@{ $all_samples{$k} }){
            my @element = split(' ', $element);
            if ($file =~ m/$element[0]/) {
                push @{$all_samples{$element}}, $file;
            }
            else {
                next;
            }
        }
    }

}

foreach my $k (keys %all_samples) {
    foreach my $element (@{ $all_samples{$k} }) {
        print $element,"\n";
    }
}
```

But the output is not what I expected

```
AANB    John    male
SBBA.txt1
S00V    Sara    female
SBBA    Anna    female
S00V.txt1
AANB.txt1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that

```
        my @element = split(' ', $element);
        if ($file =~ m/$element[0]/) {
            push @{$all_samples{$element}}, $file;
        }
```

Is not doing the right thing, so `$all_samples{$element}}` is a new arrayref. You're printing six one element arrays rather than three  two element arrays.

But then it doesn't help that you're printing the array elements one per line.

I think that your final section should look more like this:

```
foreach my $k (keys %all_samples) {
    print join( "\t", @{ $all_samples{$k} } ) . "\n"
}
```

In general, I think that you're overcomplicating this script. Here's how I would write it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $all_samples={};

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    # Note that I'm using variable names here to document
    # The format of the file being read. This makes for
    # easier trouble-shooting -- if a column is missing,
    # It's easier to tell that $file_base_name shouldn't be
    # 'Anna' than that $line[0] should not be 'Anna'.
    my ( $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ) = split("\t", $_);
    push(@{$all_samples->{$file_base_name} }, ( $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ) );
}

my $dir = ".";
opendir(DIR, $dir);
my @files = grep(/\.txt$/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

FILE: foreach my $file (@files) {
    BASE: foreach my $base (keys %{$all_samples}){
        next BASE unless( $file =~ /$base/ );
        push @{$all_samples->{$base}}, $file;
    }
}

foreach my $k (keys %{$all_samples} ) {
    print join( "\t", @{ $all_samples->{$k} } ) . "\n";
}
```

I prefer hashrefs to hashes, simply because I tend to deal with nested data structures -- I'm simply more used to seeing `$all_samples->{$k}` than `$all_samples{$k}`... more importantly, I'm using the full power of the arrayref, meaning that I'm not having to re-split the array that's already been split once.

G. Cito brings up an interesting point: why did I use

```
push(@{$all_samples->{$file_base_name} }, ( $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ) );
```

Rather than

```
push(@{$all_samples->{$file_base_name} }, [ $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ] );
```

There's nothing syntactically wrong with the latter, but it wasn't what I was trying to accomplish:

Let's look at what $all_samples->{$base} would look like after

```
push @{$all_samples->{$base}}, $file;
```

If the original push had been this:

```
push(@{$all_samples->{$file_base_name} }, [ $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ] );
```

`@{$all_samples->{$base}}` would look like this:

```
(
    [ $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ],
    $file
)
```

If instead, we use

```
push(@{$all_samples->{$file_base_name} }, ( $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ) );
```

`@{$all_samples->{$base}}` looks like this after `push @{$all_samples->{$base}}, $file`:

```
(
    $file_base_name, 
    $given_name, 
    $sex, 
    $file
)
```

For instance:

```
(
    "AANB",
    "John",   
    "male",    
    "AANB.txt"
)
```

So when we print the array:

```
print join( "\t", @{ $all_samples->{$k} } ) . "\n";
```

Will print

```
AANB    John    male    AANB.txt
```

Comment: Nice self documenting with variable names.  Good practice (*mea culpa*!).  Possible  typo? don't  you want `[ $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex  ]` rather than `( $file_base_name, $given_name, $sex ) `?

Answer (score 1):

Here is somewhat simpler way of creating the hash of arrays - reading from `DATA` here instead of a file only for convenience:

```
#!perl
use strict ;
use warnings ; 
use Data::Dumper ;

my $samples  ; 

while (<DATA>){
      chomp;
      map { $samples->{$_->[0]} = [@$_[1..2]] } [ split/\s+/ ];
 }

 push @{$samples->{$_}} , $_.".txt" for keys %$samples ;

 print  Dumper  \$samples ;

 __DATA__
AANB    John    male
S00V    Sara    female
SBBA    Anna    female
```

Since the filenames are known, you can just construct them from strings. Or is that not possible ?  Perhaps confirming they exist with a file test (see `perldoc -f -X`) before pushing onto the array would avoid creating bad data but still allow you to build the entries this way.